# Derived Class not Calling Entire Base Constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, derived-class

I'm sure this is just some stupid syntax error I'm making, but when my class `CNeck` derived from `CLimb` calls its default constructor, `CNeck()` everything works as expected. When it calls a different constructor `CNeck(*parent)` it seems to call about half of the specified base constructor, then gives uses the compiler default constructor or something weird.

main.cpp

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CNeck neck01;
    CLimb *ptr;
    ptr = &neck01;
    CNeck neck02(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

limb.h (parent class)

```
class CLimb
{
public:
    CLimb(void);
    CLimb(CLimb *_parent);
    ~CLimb(void);

    float cut;
    float bone;
    float resistance;
    //attributes
    bool isBurned;
    bool isBleeding;
    bool isOnFire;
    bool isNeedFirstaid;

    CLimb *parent;
};
```

limb.cpp (parent class)

```
#include "limb.h"

CLimb::CLimb(void) :
    cut(10),
    bone(10),
    resistance(10),
    //attributes
    isBurned(0),
    isBleeding(0),
    isOnFire(0),
    isNeedFirstaid(0)
{
    parent = NULL;
}

CLimb::CLimb(CLimb *_parent) :
    cut(10),
    bone(10),
    resistance(10),
    //attributes
    isBurned(0),
    isBleeding(0),
    isOnFire(0),
    isNeedFirstaid(0)

{
    parent = _parent;
}

CLimb::~CLimb(void)
{
}
```

neck.h (child class)

```
#include "limb.h"
class CNeck :
    public CLimb
{
public:
    CNeck(void);
    CNeck(CLimb *_parent);
    ~CNeck(void);
};
```

**neck.cpp (child class)**

```
#include "Neck.h"


CNeck::CNeck(void)
{
}

CNeck::CNeck(CLimb *_parent) : CLimb(*_parent)
{
}

CNeck::~CNeck(void)
{
}
```

As you can see, the child class doesn't do anything other than call the parent's constructor, yet when I step through the program I get the following results:
`CNeck neck01;`: normal
`CNeck neck02(ptr);`: values cut, bone, resistance, and isBurned all have proper values, but isBleeding, isOnFire, and isNeedFirstaid all equal 1 instead of zero. The body of CNeck::CNeck(*parent) is still executed.
When I was testing and called `CLimb limb(ptr);` instead of `CNeck neck02(ptr);` all the values were assigned the correct values.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is marked `CLimb(CLimb *_parent);` meaning it takes a *pointer to a CLimb* but in the `CNeck` constructor,

```
CNeck::CNeck(CLimb *_parent) : CLimb(*_parent)
```

you're *dereferencing the pointer*, which calls `CLimb(CLimb&)` which is the copy constructor. Turn `*_parent` into `_parent` to resolve this problem. Plus you might want to define a copy constructor as well.

In other news, don't do this:

```
CLimb *ptr;
ptr = &hand;
```

Do this:

```
CLimb *ptr = &hand;
```

To avoid wasting cycles.

And you also don't need `void` in the parameter list for functions which take no parameters (that's the way C does it, not C++). So for example:

```
CLimb(void);
CLimb(CLimb *_parent);
~CLimb(void);
```

Should be

```
CLimb();
CLimb(CLimb *_parent);
~CLimb();
```

I know it's not related to your question, but it's good style.

Answer (score 2):

```
CNeck::CNeck(CLimb *_parent) : CLimb(*_parent)
```

should be

```
CNeck::CNeck(CLimb *_parent) : CLimb(_parent)
```

Besides, I don't really understand how this compiled:

```
ptr = &hand;
```

`hand` is not declared at all, but looks like you missed it while copy pasting the code here.